# Install Perl Module Nginx

Tags: perl, nginx, perl-module

I am following [this tutorial](http://rile5.com/topic/36230-nginx-browser-integrity-check/) and got an error with perl_modules:

```
root@ns516302:~# service nginx restart
Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "perl_modules" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
root@ns516302:~#
```

How do I install perl_module into nginx?

There is not much info on [this link](https://www.google.com/search?q=ngx_http_perl_module&oq=ngx_http_perl_module&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4j69i60.280j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8#q=ngx_http_perl_module+install).

Comment: How did you install nginx in the first place?

Comment: apt-get install nginx -y

Comment: There are several `nginx-*` packages. Default one (`nginx-core`) doesn't contain perl. You should install `nginx-extras` package

Comment: Alexey, thank you for getting back to me. I have install the nginx-extas package. Here is the new output "
Restarting nginx: nginx: [alert] version 1.2.1 of nginx.pm is required, but 1.4.4 was found
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
"

Comment: Probably it's in your perl module.

Comment: Ok I moved the perl module to the correct folder.

I did a complete reinstall of my server and installed the nginx-extras and now I get this errror

http://prntscr.com/7iwbw1

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx-extras
```

Answer (score 1):

Recompile `nginx` with the `--with-http_perl_module` option to `./configure`.